# Search sentence for all values in a list of values and return all found into adjacent cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to search for values from a list in Sheet1 in each cell of column C on sheet2 to be separated by commas.

Sheet1 has a list of names:
[image]

Sheet 2 has a set of sentences in column C. The output in column D should be the names in Sheet1.
[image]

I have searched but haven't found a solution.

I don't have any code to show that has been effective in this regard but I did come across a function that seemed promising but, since I don't know what would surround the name per cell it isn't quite what I need.

```
Function RegexExtract(ByVal text As String, _
                      ByVal extract_what As String, _
                      Optional separator As String = ", ") As String

Dim allMatches As Object
Dim RE As Object
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim result As String

RE.Pattern = extract_what
RE.Global = True
Set allMatches = RE.Execute(text)

For i = 0 To allMatches.Count - 1
    For j = 0 To allMatches.Item(i).submatches.Count - 1
        result = result & (separator & allMatches.Item(i).submatches.Item(j))
    Next
Next

If Len(result) <> 0 Then
    result = Right$(result, Len(result) - Len(separator))
End If

RegexExtract = result

End Function
```

Comment: If you have TEXTJOIN, this can be done with a formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using regexp `Test`:

```
Function CheckList(ByVal text As String, list As Range) As String

    Static RE As Object
    Dim arr, sep, r As Long, result As String, v

    If RE Is Nothing Then Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    If Len(text) > 0 Then
        arr = list.Value
        'check each name
        For r = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
            v = arr(r, 1)
            If Len(v) > 0 Then
                RE.Pattern = "\b" & v & "\b" '<< whole word only
                If RE.test(text) Then
                    result = result & sep & v
                    sep = ", " 'populate the separator
                End If
            End If
        Next r
    End If
    CheckList = result
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

Scott showed how to use `TEXTJOIN`, when you don't have access to this function. Your best best might be VBA. We could emulate some sort of `TEXTJOIN`, possibly like so:

```
Function ExtractNames(nms As Range, str As Range) As String
    ExtractNames = Join(Filter(Evaluate("TRANSPOSE(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" & nms.Address & "," & str.Address & "))," & nms.Address & ",""|""))"), "|", False), ", ")
End Function
```

Called in `D2` like: `=ExtractNames($A$2:$A$7,C2)` and dragged down. *Downside* of this `Evalate` method is that it's making use of an array formula, however the native `TEXTJOIN` would have been so too. *Plusside* is that it's avoiding iteration.

---

***<sub>EDIT</sub>***

As @TimWilliams correctly stated, this might end up confusing substrings that hold part of what we are looking for, e.g. > `Paul` in `Pauline`.

I also realized that to overcome this, we need to substitute special characters. I've rewritten my function to the below:

```
Function ExtractNames(nms As Range, str As Range) As String

Dim chr() As Variant, arr As Variant

'Create an array of characters to ignore
chr = Array("!", ",", ".", "?")

'Get initial array of all characters, with specified characters in chr substituted for pipe symbol
arr = Evaluate("TRANSPOSE(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(MID(" & str.Address & ",ROW(A1:A" & Len(str.Value) & "),1),{""" & Join(chr, """,""") & """},0)),""|"",MID(" & str.Address & ",ROW(A1:A" & Len(str.Value) & "),1)))")

'Get array of words used to check against names without any specified characters
arr = Split(Join(Filter(arr, "|", False), ""), " ")

'Check which names occur in arr
For Each cl In nms
    If IsNumeric(Application.Match(cl.Value, arr, 0)) Then
        If ExtractNames = "" Then
            ExtractNames = cl.Value
        Else
            ExtractNames = Join(Array(ExtractNames, cl.Value), ", ")
        End If
    End If
Next cl

End Function
```

As you can tell, it's possible still, but my conclusion and recommendation would be to go with `RegEx`. @TimWilliams has a great answer explaining this, which I slightly adapted to prevent an extra iteration:

```
Function ExtractNames(nms As Range, str As Range) As String

Dim regex As Object: Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
Dim arr() As Variant: arr = Application.Transpose(nms.Value)
Dim del As String

regex.Pattern = "\b(?:" & Join(arr, "|") & ")\b"
regex.Global = True
regex.Ignorecase = True

Set hits = regex.Execute(str.Value)
For Each hit In hits
    ExtractNames = ExtractNames & del & hit
    del = ", "
Next hit

End Function
```

Or even without iteration:

```
Function ExtractNames(nms As Range, str As Range) As String

Dim regex As Object: Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
Dim arr() As Variant: arr = Application.Transpose(nms.Value)
Dim del As String

regex.Global = True
regex.Ignorecase = True

'Perform 1st replace on non-alphanumeric characters
regex.Pattern = "[^\w]"
ExtractNames = Application.Trim(regex.Replace(str.Value, " "))

'Perferom 2nd replace on all words that are not in arr
regex.Pattern = "\b(?!" & Join(arr, "|") & ")[\w-]+\b"
ExtractNames = Application.Trim(regex.Replace(ExtractNames, " "))

ExtractNames = Replace(ExtractNames, " ", ", ")

End Function
```

Comment: Would this match "Paul" with "Pauline"?

Comment: Good catch @TimWilliams, you are completely right. I have been puzzling together an approach to counter this but came to the conclusion `RegEx` is the way to go. So I would recommend OP to use your solution. I have made a slight adaptation on your code myself.

Comment: Thank you both for the discussion, it helped me to better understand the problem. I have accepted @TimWilliams function as the answer but both work great. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Dictionary object to check each string against the NameList, assuming that the names in the sample string do not have punctuation.

If they do, this method can still be used, but would require some modification.  For example, one could replace all of the punctuation with spaces; or do something else depending on how complex things might be.

eg:

```
Option Explicit
Function ckNameList(str As String, nameList As Range) As String
    Dim D As Dictionary
    Dim vNames, I As Long, V, W
    Dim sOut As String

vNames = nameList

Set D = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    D.CompareMode = TextCompare

For I = 1 To UBound(vNames)
    If Not D.Exists(vNames(I, 1)) Then _
        D.Add vNames(I, 1), vNames(I, 1)
Next I

V = Split(str, " ")
sOut = ""
For Each W In V
    If D.Exists(W) Then _
        sOut = sOut & ", " & W
Next W

ckNameList = Mid(sOut, 3)

End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question, Ron. I think the previous answer works a little better for my purposes but this is an interesting solution. Appreciate your help.